# How to write an easy Conjugate Function that just replaces i -> -i

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, complex

I have a complicated complex expression that can Mathematica can't simplify using neither `FullSimplify`, `Simplify` nor `Refine`.

I tried something very naive

```
myConjugate[expr_] := expr /. {a_ I :> - a I}
expr = I (a + 0.5123 I b - 1.2332 I c);
myConjugate[expr]
Refine[Conjugate[expr], Element[{a, b, c}, Reals]]
% - %% // Simplify
```

which should give 0, but doesn't.

So my question becomes,

how can I flip the signs of all `I`s in an expression? The faster the better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace acts on the full form of an expression, not the displayed form. The full form of your expression:

expr = I (a + 0.5123 I b - 1.2332 I c);
expr // FullForm

[image]

Therefore a complex number is represented by: `Complex[..,..]`. Therefore to make your "myConjugate" work you need to write:

```
myConjugate[expr_] := expr /. { Complex[x_, y_] -> Complex[x, -y]}
expr = I (a + 0.5123 I b - 1.2332 I c);
myConjugate[expr]
Refine[Conjugate[expr], Element[{a, b, c}, Reals]]
% - %% // Simplify
```

(* 0 *)